# How to upload a file using node js streams and HTML forms?

Tags: node.js, forms, file-upload, stream

I want to upload a file using NodeJS streams and HTML forms. I have a simple server.
It is working when I upload the file using Postman. But when I upload through HTML form, the file is uploaded but is not readable. How to do it?

This is `index.js`:

```
const app = require('express')();
const fs = require('fs');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.post('/file-upload', (req, res) => {
    const filePath = 'uploads/uploaded-file';
    const stream = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
    req.pipe(stream);
    stream.on('close', () => {
        res.send({ status: 'success', filePath })
    });
});

// Start server
app.listen(3000, () => console.log("The server is running at localhost:3000"));
```

This is `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/file-upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file">
        <input type="submit" name="upload">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the postman request screenshot:
[image: postman screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

As you can see you're trying to upload the file through a form using `multipart/form-data` whereas you're uploading it as `binary` in postman.

To fix this you can setup up a `multipart/form-data` parser on your server side (e.g. using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)), which would look something like this:

```
const multer  = require('multer')
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })
// ...

app.post('/file-upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    res.send({ status: 'success', filePath: req.file.path })        
});
```

Comment: @martinho: any feedback?